# GROUP BY with flagged value

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00979

Below query is to return flag as Y if `c.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP < MAX(t.LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP)`

```
SELECT
'Y' as CAN_UPDATE, t.LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP
FROM CUSTOMERS c
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS t ah on (c.customer_id = t.customer_id)
WHERE
t.status_active_flag = 'Y' and  c.customer_ID ='CUST_019'
GROUP BY t.LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP
HAVING c.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP < MAX(t.LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP);
```

ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression encountered, understand that all columns in SELECT need to be included in GROUP BY clause. How can handle for the flagged value 'Y' in this case?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column c.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP need to be added to group by part as well

```
GROUP BY t.LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP, c.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP
```

here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=24641f85b3e4b364d4f5ff5d9fb6c291) with a dumb example

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING` clause will effectively change the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` and you can, since you are taking the maximum of the column you are grouping by and aggregating on that column is irrelevant as there will only be a singular value per group, then move the `HAVING` comparison to the `ON` clause of the join without aggregation:

```sql
SELECT 'Y' as CAN_UPDATE,
       t.LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP
FROM   CUSTOMERS c
       INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS t
       ON (   c.customer_id = t.customer_id
          AND c.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP < t.LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP
          )
WHERE  t.status_active_flag = 'Y'
AND    c.customer_id ='CUST_019'
GROUP BY t.LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP;
```

You could also use a `DISTINCT` (or `UNIQUE`) clause instead of the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: If I put c.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP < MAX(ah.WW_LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP) to the ON clause, error encounter ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Comment: @user2102665 This is the first time you mention a `WW_LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP` column. If you mean `LATEST_ACTION_TIMESTAMP` then you are grouping by that column so there will only ever be one value per group and taking the maximum does not make sense; just compare it without using `MAX` (as I did in my answer).